# Как сложить время двух дат?

Tags: c#

Есть две даты:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(0001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 5);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(0001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 5);
```

- Как сложить только время двух дат?
- Как к одной дате прибавить только часы/минуты/секунды другой даты?

Comment: [TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Свойство [DateTime.TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает TimeSpan, соответствующий интервал дня, прошедший с полуночи.

метод [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx) у DateTime, принимает TimeSpan, поэтому прибавление времени к дате может выглядеть так:

```
DateTime date = date1.Add(date2.TimeOfDay);
```